# If an astronaut could remove their helmet in space, would Flight Control hear any sound during depressurization?

Tags: gas, astronaut

I assume it all comes down to how long would it take for the oxygen in an astronaut's helmet to evacuate.

I figured it would happen in less than a second, and no sound would be picked up by the astronaut's comm.

Comment: There would be brief wind noise as the air rushes past the mic out into space, which would definitely be picked up.

Comment: I found this in the VTC queue. Please remember that [real-world questions are on-topic](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6161/40609), although there should be some worldbuilding context. However, all things considered, this is a cool enough question that I'm willing to skip the worldbuilding context.

Comment: @JBH "Coolness" is a matter of personal opinion and not a valid reason to leave a question open when it's a question asking about the real world. This is not a worldbuilding topic; it would be better suited for Physics or Space Exploration.

Comment: The open-in-space faceplate seems quite an impressive design flaw...but perfect for 3-stooges-style physical comedy.

Answer (score 11):

### About 15 seconds and they'll hear wind.

I tried calculating this exactly and ended up with a lot of "depends". Human bodies swell pretty quickly when exposed to vacuum and this could partially seal the neck, slowing the wind to a long hiss.

Theres a reserve oxygen supply in the backpack. They mostly filter co2 for the 8 hours of use but they can replenish consumed or leaked oxygen. That will be depleted fairly quickly. I cant find specs on maximum flow rate of this system but it will not be instant. 15 seconds is an educated guess from the diagrams of the system I can find.

The wont hear screams as mouth and lungs will be in vacuum allmost immediately, they will hear wind, hissing, and panicked movements conducted through the suit. They'll also hear alarms from monitor systems and up links.

Also the astronaut isn't instantly dead. You have 6 seconds of useful consciousness when this happens. With a bit of luck that is enough time to jump back into an airlock and smash the emergency represurise button.

Comment: I'm interested in the time of useful consciousness, do you have any source for that?

Comment: @Polygnome https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_useful_consciousness#:~:text=Time%20of%20useful%20consciousness%20(TUC,environment%20of%20inadequate%20oxygen%20supply.

Comment: @Polygnome It's basically the time it takes blood to go from the lungs to the brain.  For those few seconds the brain still has normal oxygen, you only get in trouble when the deoxygenated blood reaches the brain.

Answer (score 3):

I believe mission control will hear a very loud sound as the air screams out whatever opening it's leaving from at tremendous velocity.

As the opening gets big enough this would go away, but almost all openings start small.

Comment: Any thought what that very loud sound would sound like: an intense rush of wind, an explosive sound, a tremendous pop or a hiss?

Answer (score 1):

### yes

well sorta, lemme explain.

a microphone works by measuring the compressions(and decompressions) of air, here find the microphone on your pc and record you blowing into it. It will make a wind like sound. so your unfortunate astronaut takes off his helmet and whoooosh a whole bunch of air comes out and by the microphone. if it was simply whats left in the helmet it would seem like a pop and then silence.

of course its not just that air its all the air in the extra tanks. which means it will be some wind like sound that would get quieter and fade away pretty soon. also probably every alarm is going off.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is an unequivocal yes, and the astronaut will even be able to talk to command control.

The voice pick-ups and speakers are not regular mics, they are placed on the bones of the head and on the vocal chords. The headphones do not need air to operate, they go directly to bone conduction and into the inner ear.

[Throat microphones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throat_microphone) can pick up the vibration of the vocal chords. Head mics can pick up the vocal vibrations through the bones.

Both of these are used in fighter jet communication systems, military field units,  biohazzard suits, scuba gear, and in astronaut helmets. With Covid, they are even being used in operating theatres and emerency rooms.

The astronaut could continue hearing ground control as long as life and power held out, and could speak as long as there was any air left in the throat, and probably a while after. How much air is actually in the helmet is not relevant. The ear drums do not even have to be intact.

Comment: What is the source of your information? In this clip https://youtu.be/yaVVns_sTGY?t=609 from a shuttle launch two microphones are visible at the sides of the astronauts' mouths, which they keep on adjusting. On the NASA website it talks about the plans to stop using the Snoopy Cap (CCA) and use an "integrated audio system where the microphones and earphones are removed from the Communications Carrier Assembly and integrated into the structure of the space suit itself." https://www.nasa.gov/topics/moonmars/features/hatsman.html

Comment: @Bob516 I gave the link in the article, 'Throat microphones' is the linking word.

Comment: That wikipedia link explains how the throat microphones work, but doesn't describe them as being used by any space agency. How would it even work in a vacuum since the vocal cords need air passing though them to vibrate? The lungs would empty of air very quickly and the astronaut would not be able to vocalize.